# Convert a string to a any data type in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, enums

I am trying to create a generic function to convert any string to any data type.
For example

```kotlin
convert<Int>("23")  =>  23
convert<LocalDateTime>("2022-06-29T18:02:00")  =>  LocalDateTime object 
convert<String>("hg")  =>  "hg"
```

and throw an error if not possible.

This is the code used to do that without any error handling.

```kotlin
/**
* Convert a string to given class type or throw an error if it is not valid
*/
inline fun <reified T> stringToTypeOrError(value: String): T {
    val v: T = when (T::class) {
        Int::class -> value.toInt() as T
        String::class -> value as T
        Double::class -> value.toDouble() as T
        LocalDateTime::class -> LocalDateTime.parse(value) as T
        else -> throw BadRequestException("Does Not Support : $value.")
    }
    return v
}
```

But I face a problem when I try to convert string to enums.
For example, if I need to convert to an enum.

```kotlin
convert<Order>("asc")  =>  Order.ASC
```

For supporting all enums I tried this:

```kotlin
enum class Order { ASC, DESC }

/**
 * Convert a string to enum or throw a custom error
 */
inline fun <reified E : Enum<E>> enumValueOrError(value: String): E {
    return try {
        enumValueOf(value)
    } catch (e: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) {
        throw BadRequestException("Does Not Support : $value.")
    }
}

/**
* Convert a string to a given class type or throw an error if it is not valid
*/
inline fun <reified T> stringToTypeOrError(value: String): T {
    // TODO: Handle all exceptions
    val v: T = when (T::class) {
        Int::class -> value.toInt() as T
        String::class -> value as T
        Double::class -> value.toDouble() as T
        LocalDateTime::class -> LocalDateTime.parse(value) as T
        else -> {
            if (T::class.javaClass.isEnum) {
                return enumValueOrError<T>(value)
            } else {
                throw NotImplementedError("Not implemented for type:${T::class.qualifiedName}")
            }
        }
    }
    return v
}
```

build fails saying:

```
Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'Enum<TypeVariable(E)>'
```

in line  `return enumValueOrError<T>(value)`

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Or how can i pass the generic type `T` in `enumValueOrError` function
(Without adding each enum inside the `when` case)

Comment: If you want to scale this solution, I would suggest creating a custom format for `kotlinx.serialization`: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/formats.md#custom-formats-experimental

Comment: A very ugly solution would be to call `java.lang.Enum.valueOf` using reflection.

Answer (score 2):

This case is very similar to unchecked casts where we usually suppress the warning. Even if in your case this is not a warning, but an error, Kotlin still allows us to suppress it:

```kotlin
@Suppress("UPPER_BOUND_VIOLATED")
return enumValueOrError<T>(value)
```

Additionally, you have a bug in your code where you check for `T::class.javaClass.isEnum`. You should check for `T::class.java.isEnum` instead. You can also skip Java reflection entirely with: `T::class.isSubclassOf(Enum::class)`.

Finally, it seems not a good idea to create such a big inline function. It will greatly affect the size of the resulting bytecode. I suggest to split this function into two: internal function that receives `KClass<T>` and inline reified function that just invokes the first one. Unfortunately, this way you'll lose ability to use `enumValueOf()` utility.